lightning-datatable showing currency in EUR in a USD-only org
I am working in an org WITHOUT multi-currency enabled, and the Currency Locale is "English (United States) - USD".  I have confirmed this in setup.  My user's locale is "English (United States)", which shouldn't matter in a non-multi-currency org, but I did check it.
I am working in a W'25 Sandbox; I need to make an update to an existing LWC that contains a lightning-datatable; one of the columns is a currency column.  While testing (and before making any changes), I'm seeing all of the currency values with the Euro symbol (€) instead of the Dollar symbol ($).  I have confirmed that this is not the case in the production org.
This is my columns array for the datatable, the column in question is the "Price" column:
columns = [
    {label: "Title", fieldName: "title", displayReadOnlyIcon: true, hideDefaultActions: true, initialWidth: 200},
    {label: "Price", fieldName: "price", type: "currency", editable: true, hideDefaultActions: true, initialWidth: 110 },
    {label: "Price Unit", fieldName: "priceUnit", editable: true, hideDefaultActions: true, initialWidth: 120},
    {label: "Description", fieldName: "description", editable: true, hideDefaultActions: true, wrapText:true, initialWidth: 175},
    {type: 'action', typeAttributes: {rowActions: this.getRowActions.bind(this)}}
];

I have confirmed (via console.log) that the price field values in the data array are just numbers, with no currency info.  According to the lightning-datatable docs,

Currency type displays a value based on the org currency and your Salesforce locale by default.
To override the default currency code, pass in a custom currencyCode value.

As stated, this is a single-currency org in US Dollars.  Every currency field on record pages shows the $ symbol.
Finally, I have tried adding typeAttributes: { currencyCode: 'USD' } to the column definition, and it did fix the problem.  I guess I'll leave it in, but why was that needed?

Indeed strange! Have you tried how a stand-alone, newly inserted lightning-formatted-number renders currency in the same LWC? Emptied the browser cache, disabled "secure and persistent browser caching"? What does utilizing @salesforce/i18n/internationalizationProperty say about currency?
